# How do I deploy multiple versions of my app with routes using Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, routes, yaml, gcloud

I have an AppEngine project on https://myproject.appspot.com and I would like to be able to supply different versions of `myproject` if I, let's say, want to break backwards compatibility. The convenient way would be to have something like this:

https://myproject.appspot.com/v2 --> version 2 of my `myproject`

https://myproject.appspot.com/v3 --> version 3 of my `myproject`

I know I can deploy custom versions by doing: `gcloud app deploy --version=v3`. However, how do I fix this routing? Apparently, the different versions get their respective URL:s as desribed here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-routed. The pattern is `https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`. This means that I would have `https://v2-dot-myproject.appspot.com` and `https://v3-dot-myproject.appspot.com`.

So, how do I do the routing? AFAIK I can't add this to `dispatch.yaml`. There I can only route to services and not versions or exact URLs.

Comment: Won't `https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com` work for your tests?

Answer (score 1):

The `https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com` format is the preferred way to manage versions in GAE. This gives you get the ability to [split traffic between versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/splitting-traffic), which is very powerful for canary testing or a/b split testing.

If you were really interested to have `https://myproject.appspot.com/[version numbers]` then you could just roll out one version of your app with `https://myproject.appspot.com/v2` and `https://myproject.appspot.com/v3` routes all in the same version, but then you won't be able to split traffic via GAE routing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything specifically to obtain this routing, GAE does it for you automatically.

Just deploy the way you mentioned and checkout the respective URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Google has described it here: [how-requests-are-routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-routed)

Page says request can be routed to specific url by adding version number to url like below

`https://[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`

If I have a project by named `http://mycuteproject.appspot.com`, then after reading above page I will think that a specific version can be accessed by `http://20190705t200049.mycuteproject.appspot.com`. But it is not like that, the url  should be `https://20190705t200049-dot-mycuteproject.appspot.com`